# I was creating an simon game using javascript but i got an error on console:

Tags: javascript, html

**Please give me the solution for this code**
**I was creating an simon game using javascript but i got an error on console:**

*The error: Uncaught ReferenceError: randomChosenColour is not defined
at game.js:3:20
(anonymous) @ game.js:3*

index.html file code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Simon</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Press+Start+2P" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <h1 id="level-title">Press A Key to Start</h1>
  <div class="container">
    <div lass="row">

      <div type="button" id="green" class="btn green">

      </div>

      <div type="button" id="red" class="btn red">

      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">

      <div type="button" id="yellow" class="btn yellow">

      </div>
      <div type="button" id="blue" class="btn blue">

      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="game.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

game.js code:

```
var buttonColours = ["red", "blue", "green", "yellow"];
var gamePattern = [randomChosenColour];

function nextSequence(params) {
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
    var randomChosenColour = buttonColours[randomNumber];
    gamePattern.push(randomChosenColour);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because by the time you declare `gamePattern`, `randomChosenColour` *is not defined* yet.

You just need to declare the `gamePattern` array to be an empty array.

```
var gamePattern = [];
```